# use PHP library in Custom Controller

Tags: composer

I have a custom module and in its controller i am using 'namespace + classname' format to included QRCode library (which is in root/vendor/).

I have used composer to install library

Now I am trying to use this library in custom controller

```
namespace Drupal\product_display\Controller;
use Endroid\QrCode\QrCode;
```

But I am getting 'class not found error'

```
Error: Class 'Endroid\QrCode\QrCode' not found
```

Class doesn't autoload.

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried dump-autoload command too -

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Ref: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload-dumpautoload-